# Problem involving inequality, first derivative and second derivative

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, derivatives

Let $f: \Bbb R \to (0, \infty)$ be a function twice differentiable with the property that $(f'(x))^2 \gt f(x) f''(x)$ for every $x \in \Bbb R$. Show that $$\left( f(x_1) \times (f(x_2))^2 \times (f(x_3))^3 \right)^ {\frac 1 6} \le \frac 1 6 \left( f(x_1)+2f(x_2)+3f(x_3) \right)$$ for every $x_1,x_2,x_3 \in \Bbb R.$

Comment: Hint:  AM-GM inequality and $$f(x_1)+2f(x_2)+3f(x_3)=f(x_1)+f(x_2)+f(x_2)+f(x_3)+f(x_3)+f(x_3)$$, but.. I think  $(f'(x))^2>f(x)f''(x)$ is not necessary. (?)

Comment: In case you don't know AM-GM inequality refers to [Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Background).